# What is "Pass the hash" attack?

Tags: authentication, hash

The article on Wikipedia doesn't explain how the attacker can authenticate to the remote server using the hash instead of the original password. According to the following article the attack is still possible even with recent versions of MS Windows

https://samsclass.info/lulz/pth-8.1.htm

Also is this attack limited only to MS Windows?

Comment: I appreciate that you're just learning, but we do expect you to do your own research before asking questions here.  If I paste the title of your question into Google, the very first result is [this excellent paper from SANS](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/testing/pass-the-hash-attacks-tools-mitigation-33283).

Comment: I apologize if I ask lots of questions but no paper simplify complex stuff like you do guys (including yourself). I see my questions as creating a simplified reference for all the beginners like myself. I really appreciate your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pass the Hash" is a combined weakness of windows and NTLM, which can be exploited in a corporate environment if one administrator account with the same password is used for multiple computers, to gain access to all of those computers.

From the [Wikipedia NTLM article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager#NTLM_and_Kerberos):

> The NTLM protocol uses one or both of two hashed password values, both of which are also stored on the server (or domain controller), and which are password equivalent, meaning that if you grab the hash value from the server, you can authenticate without knowing the actual password.

In theory also other operation systems can be affected. Its mostly a weakness of NTLM. NTLM is really terribly designed. Protecting a hash as a secret is very hard, its the wrong approach in my opinion.

There are other mechanisms that also rely on hashes as a common secret. SCRAM is one example. However SCRAM uses a salted hash, and when the salt is made unique per computer, so will be the range of pass-the-hash.